# Htaccess redirect to directory when rss.xml/ occurs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, rss

Hai I am having a problem with my wp site , I have some plugin installed which set all my rss urls to

```
http://www.domain.com/post_title/rss.xml/
```

I want to redirect it to

```
http://www.domain.com/post_title/feed/
```

I am just getting started with htaccess , wrote a code but not worked

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/rss$ http://www.domain.com/$1/feed/
```

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick this rule as your **very first rule** in WP .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/rss\.xml/$ /$1/feed/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: With little change : RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/rss\.xml/$ /$1/feed/ [L,NC,R=301]